# Unfortunately <program name> has stopped. Android rock paper scissors game

Tags: java, android

Okay so I'm making a simple rock, paper, scissors game for android. 
So far I have the following:

```
package com.example.digitoolz;

import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private int userChoice;
    private int compChoice;

    private int userScore = 0;
    private int compScore = 0;

    private Toast winnerToast;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_button);


        ImageButton rockbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rock_button);
        rockbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                userChoice = 0;         
                compChoiceSelector();
                winSelect();
            }
        });

        ImageButton paperbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.paper_button);
        paperbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                userChoice = 1;         
                compChoiceSelector();
                winSelect();
            }
        });


        ImageButton scissorsbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.scissors_button);
        scissorsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                userChoice = 2;     
                compChoiceSelector();
                winSelect();
            }
        });
    }   

        public void compChoiceSelector(){
            Random ran = new Random();
            compChoice = ran.nextInt(0) + 3;
        }

        public void winSelect(){
            if(userChoice == compChoice){
                winnerToast.setText("It's a Draw!");
                }else if (userChoice == 0 && compChoice == 1){
                    winnerToast.setText("Paper beats Rock! You Lose!");
                    compScore++;
                }else if (userChoice == 0 && compChoice == 2){
                    winnerToast.setText("Rock beats Scissorcs! You Win!");
                    userScore++;
                }else if (userChoice == 1 && compChoice == 0){
                    winnerToast.setText("Paper beats Rock! You Win!");
                    userScore++;
                }else if (userChoice == 1 && compChoice == 2){
                    winnerToast.setText("Scissors beats paper! You Lose!");
                    compScore++;
                }else if (userChoice == 2 && compChoice == 0){
                    winnerToast.setText("Rock beats scissors! You Lose!");
                    compScore++;
                }else if (userChoice == 2 && compChoice == 1){
                    winnerToast.setText("Scissors beats paper... You Win.");
                    userScore++;
            }else{
                    winnerToast.setText("");
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, when it come to pressing any of the 3 buttons(rock, paper or scissors). I get a popup saying "Unfortunately digitoolz has stopped working.

I have no idea why this is happening!?
Please can someone help me!

Thank you to all in advance! :)

```
12-21 01:02:19.711: D/AndroidRuntime(573): Shutting down VM
12-21 01:02:19.721: W/dalvikvm(573): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:187)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.example.digitoolz.GameActivity.compChoiceSelector(GameActivity.java:59)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.example.digitoolz.GameActivity$2.onClick(GameActivity.java:40)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-21 01:02:19.782: E/AndroidRuntime(573):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 01:07:20.110: I/Process(573): Sending signal. PID: 573 SIG: 9
```

new Logcat:

```
12-21 02:33:17.920: D/AndroidRuntime(11568): Shutting down VM
12-21 02:33:17.920: W/dalvikvm(11568): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abca08)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568): java.lang.RuntimeException: This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.widget.Toast.setText(Toast.java:277)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at com.example.digitoolz.GameActivity.winSelect(GameActivity.java:65)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at com.example.digitoolz.GameActivity$2.onClick(GameActivity.java:42)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14319)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-21 02:33:17.930: E/AndroidRuntime(11568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post a snip of your logcat output.

Comment: Even we don't have idea too until you post the logcat !!!!!!!

Comment: Where do you initialize `winnerToast`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that `nextInt()` needs a number above 0. Anything supplied to `nextInt()` that is `<= 0` throws that `IllegalArgumentException`.

Your other problem may be:
You don't seem to be instantiating your `winnerToast`. It is global, but your code never actually does `winnerToast = new Toast(this);` You should probably add this line of code in your `onCreate()` method to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Hi, A-C, I've now initialised winnerToast.

So regarding to the nextInt() number, should I make my numbers begin from 1? e.g rock is 1, paper is 2 and scissors 3?

Comment: @magg93 No, as `nextInt()`'s doc says: `Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)`. So pass off 3 to this method, that way you get 0, or 1, or 2.

Comment: @A-C So I now have, 
Random ran = new Random();
compChoice = ran.nextInt(3);

but I still get the same error?

Comment: On this same line? Try cleaning your project then reuploading to your phone.

Comment: I have   Random ran = new Random();
   compChoice = ran.nextInt(3);

I have tried cleaning but no success!

Comment: You *have* reuploaded it to your phone?

Comment: Yep, problem still remains.
I have other activities and XML files but would they affect this?

Comment: Is your stack trace the exact same? `IllegalArgumentException` at that line? This code portion should now work. 3 is valid, I was so paranoid I tried it out on my machine.

Comment: I've reuploaded my logcat! Ha, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @magg93 just use the `makeText` method instead of `setText` for your Toast. Slightly more arguments, same thing.

Comment: @A-C Thank you so so much! I've now got it sorted, all thanks to yourself! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs for [Random.nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29), the value of the argument specifies the range of available answers between 0 and the argument.  An argument of 0 like you've provided is nonsensical, so it complains.